# Composer file can't get zip file from private github repo

Tags: github, composer-php

I have a `composer` file that is attempting to grab a zip file from a private `github repo` like this...

```
{
    "name"    : "myproject/project",
    "type"    : "project",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name" : "testauthor"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "tespackages/package1",
                "type": "wordpress-plugin",
                "version": "2.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/myprivaterepo/myfile.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "tespackages/package1" : "2.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com" : "myprivatereposshkey"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the zip is returning a `404` error as it is unable to access it. I had assumed that using the `github-oauth` command would grant it access but not in this case.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this is an easy task - it took me a while to arrange some code to download from `Releases` page in private repo...

You could start here: [Download a repository archive (zip)](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#download-a-repository-archive-zip) and you need to authenticate first [Authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication).

If you have some kinda app that could do it - use it but I don't see in your code example where you pass or define Github username or access token, password, SSH key, etc...